# GIT signed tags and passphrase

Tags: linux, git, gnupg, git-sign

how can i make git auto enter my passphrase when i signed tags. is there an option like --
passphrase "my long passphrase", i did try using ssh-keygen but it did not help.

the Repository is on local and everything is done locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case anyone was interested, I did found a way for my problem.

1.Create new /usr/bin/gpg-with-passphrase with this contents

```
/usr/bin/gpg   --passphrase "My Really Long passphrase"  --batch --no-tty "$@"
```

2.make the new /usr/bin/gpg-with-passphrase executable

```
chmod 755 /usr/bin/gpg-with-passphrase
```

3.add this option to git config

```
git config gpg.program "/usr/bin/gpg-with-passphrase"
```

use "--global" for global

this way i dont have to enter my Long passphrase each time i sign a tag.

Comment: So, it seeems `gpg` does allow you to shoot yourself in the foot.  They do add this note in the manpage though: "Obviously, this is of very questionable security on a multi-user system. Don't use this option if you can avoid it."

Comment: To be safe with `$@`, remember to surround with doubles quotes: `"$@"`

Comment: There is, of course, very little point in having a passphrase in the first place if you are going to store it in plaintext in your scripts.

Comment: `echo "test" | gpg-with-passphrase --clearsig` still ask a passphrase, Git also :(

Answer (score 4):

As mipadi says, it is your GPG key password that is being requested.  You *really* don't want that on your command-line as you suggest, as that may make it visible to other users and hence compromise your security.  Knowing this, the creators of gpg and git don't let you shoot yourself in your foot like that.  Of course, that prompts the question of how to do this in an automated fashion so that you don't kill yourself typing your password a hundred times.

The `gpg-agent` is very useful for this.  You may need to install that separately from gpg (e.g., on Ubuntu, you want package `gnupg-agent`).  Then make sure `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` contains the line (uncommented):

```
use-agent
```

With the gpg-agent installed, your system may automatically invoke it for you.  If the environment variable `GPG_AGENT_INFO` is defined, then you're good to go.  Otherwise, start the agent:

```
eval $(gpg-agent --daemon --sh)
```

(That's for bash; adjust as required for other shells.)

Now when you need to unlock your GPG key, you should get a popup window (or some other method) for you to enter your password.  Once entered, you shouldn't need to enter it again, as all other requests will go to the agent, which has already unlocked your key.

Comment: I am using a shellscript to sign a tag and would like the password to be enter automatically. is there is a way or workaround to enter the password automatically.

Comment: You have to enter it once to get it into the agent; there's no getting around that.  After that, the agent has the unlocked key and can provide it without your entering a password.

Comment: I think this answer is the best, although I haven't gotten it to work fully yet. @PaulPrice, do you know why I get the message `gpg: gpg-agent is not available in this session` when I'm asked for my passphrase? How can I force Git to use the agent? Ideas?

Comment: Make sure that the agent has been started, and your `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` has `use-agent` and `GPG_AGENT_INFO` is set.  If you have trouble, try http://serverfault.com/questions/481103/gpg-agent-says-agent-exists-but-gpg-says-agent-doesnt-exist

Comment: @PaulPrice, thanks. I've done everything mentioned above, including [this](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Invoking-GPG_002dAGENT.html), but it seems like `GPG_AGENT_INFO` isn't actually set to anything. I don't quite understand what it should be set to either. :-/

Answer (score 2):

You're being asked for your GPG keychain password, not your SSH password. Enter than instead.